# Google Maps Licensing

Tags: licensing, terms-of-service

I had a question regarding the ToS of Google Maps/Earth, it can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Section 9.1.1a states that:

> (a) Free Access (No Fees). Your Maps API Implementation must be generally accessible to users without charge and must not require a fee-based subscription or other fee-based restricted access. This rule applies to Your Content and any other content in your Maps API Implementation, whether Your Content or the other content is in existence now or is added later.

and Section 9.1.2b states:

> (i) The rule in Section 9.1.1(a) (Free Access) does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is used in a mobile application that is sold for a fee through an online store and is downloadable to a mobile device that can access the online store.

Does that imply that if you created an android app that uses Maps API that costs money to buy, you're allowed to implement a subscription model? Is freemium disallowed under this?

Also, under the FAQ (found [here](http://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_commercial)), you're allowed to use a freemium model when it comes to posting?

> If you charge people to place information on your map (e.g. to list their homes for sale), but you display this information using the Google Maps API on a free part of your site, you'll also meet the Google Maps API Terms of Service.

For reference, I was planning to build a freemium Map-view based app that allowed users to post things that would show up as markers on the map (using geolocation of course) for a duration and charge more to have it permanently placed with additional options (more info, e.g. a live update of a restaurant's seating capacity).

Comment: Answering your question directly would come too close to legal advice for my comfort, given your plans. In terms of how to examine the TOS, my impression would be that given the text provided there are two plausible readings: either  §9.1.2b applies to unpaid and paid users if used in a paid mobile app sold through an online store, or 9.1.1(a) applies to unpaid users and 9.1.2b to paid users. If you aren't comfortable with that ambiguity, and don't want to pay for the advice of a business lawyer, you could do a separate 'lite' app and a 'pro' app and each clause would apply respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could it be that viewing and usage Map itself cannot be a restricted item in the application, but charging premium function is fine? That would fit the generally accessible clause.

Comment: I would create a free app that you have to pay to get additional features but I'm not sure if this would work in your case.